# datetime validation given time in unix format?

Tags: python, validation, date, datetime

I am trying to do date/time validation in python and I can achieve it using `datetime` module. My problem is, the data that I get is in epoch format. 
How do I achieve the same thing by passing epoch format?

My search in python docs has failed me so far. Any tips or leads is much appreciated.

```
datetime.datetime(year=2017, month=1,day=1) < 
datetime.datetime(year=2017,month=6,day=23,hour=2) >= datetime.datetime.now()
False

datetime.datetime(year=2017, month=1,day=1) < 
datetime.datetime(year=2017,month=6,day=24,hour=2) >= datetime.datetime.now()
True
```

Comment: Use [`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp).

Comment: Or just compare the epoch time to `time.time()`. You don't need to convert it.